# Retrieving Android contact using contentResolver on HTC 10 returns no result

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

My app creates a contact in the Android contact book with a special SYNC4 key, so we can look up our special contact (seperate from other Android contacts). However, we're unable to read the contact on a HTC 10 device. I've read about some differences between HTC devices and other Android devices concerning handling contacts, but unfortunately didn't find a good explanation or solution to this problem.

The creation of the contact works like this:

```
private static final String SPECIAL_CONTACT_KEY = "_MY_SPECIAL_CONTACT_KEY_";

// Create an operation with the special SYN4 key
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.SYNC4, SPECIAL_CONTACT_KEY);
        ops.add(builder.build());

// Add a 'given name' to the list of operations
builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
        builder.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "givenName");
        ops.add(builder.build());

// Add a 'phone number with type work' to the list of operations
builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
        builder.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_WORK);
        builder.withValue(Phone.NUMBER, "phoneNumber");
        ops.add(builder.build());

// Add a 'note' to the list of operations (to be able to visually discern the contact from other contacts)
builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
        builder.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(Note.NOTE, "note");
        ops.add(builder.build());

ContentProviderResult[] result = App.getContext().getContentResolver().applyBatch(AUTHORITY, ops);
```

The contact(s) can be retrieved like this:

```
// Retrieve our own contacts using the special SYNC4 key
Uri uri = Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};
String mySpecialSelection = RawContacts.SYNC4 + "='" + SPECIAL_CONTACT_KEY + "'";
Cursor cursor = App.getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, mySpecialSelection, null, null);
```

The cursor is filled with the correct contact data on all device, but on the HTC the cursor is empty.

Comment: why are you using `SYNC4`?

Comment: To be honest, it was already used by a collegue, and I was told it's a specific marker to discern our contact from others. I'm not sure what it does, but if you've got an advice for a better marker, please tell ;-)

You think it's related to the HTC problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't/shouldn't create a contact with null `ACCOUNT_NAME` and `ACCOUNT_TYPE`, these are called zombie contacts, and there isn't a guarantee they'll remain on the device (not only on HTC devices).

If you must create new contacts, you need to create a custom account for you app, and create new contacts/raw-contacts under that account.

See [this](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/) and [this](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/).
BTW, you don't have to have a SyncAdapter, but it makes things like updating your contact's data easier and plays nicely with the Android ecosystem.

You can then find your own `RawContacts` by querying for `ACCOUNT_TYPE = <your custom type>` in your query.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks! However, the description in the links was very extended (including an option to login by the user etc). I'll describe my solution in a seperate answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the answer of marmor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716017/retrieving-android-contact-using-contentresolver-on-htc-10-returns-no-result#answer-47731465) I've simplified account creation described in the links. I don't need my user to be able to create an account / login etc, but I just create an account myself, incl. a single contact, that's all I need.
Here's a simplified version of my code:

I made a MyAppAccountManager class like this:

```
public class MyAppAccountManager
{   
    public boolean createMyAppAccountIfNotExists(Context context)
    {
        return doesMyAppAccountExist(context) || createNewMyAppAccount(context);
    }

    public boolean createNewMyAppAccount(Context context)
    {
        Account account = new Account(context.getString(R.string.account_name), context.getString(R.string.account_type));
        boolean accountCreated = AccountManager.get(context).addAccountExplicitly(account, context.getString(R.string.account_password), null);
        if (accountCreated)
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "Account created");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "Account creation failed.");
        }
        return accountCreated;
    }

    public boolean doesMyAppAccountExist(Context context)
    {
        return AccountManager.get(context).getAccountsByType(context.getString(R.string.account_type)).length > 0;
    }
}
```

When I create the contact, I don't use the SYNC4 SPECIAL_CONTACT_KEY anymore, but the account(type & -name):

```
if (!new MyAppAccountManager().createMyAppAccountIfNotExists(context))
{
    throw new UnableToCreateContact("Could not find or create MyApp account");
}

ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, context.getString(R.string.account_type));
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, context.getString(R.string.account_name));
        ops.add(builder.build());
```

Furthermore, I need to describe my account authenticator in my manifest:

```
    <service
        android:name=".service.MyAppAuthenticatorService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator"/>
    </service>
```

which points to my authenticator service:

```
public class MyAppAuthenticatorService
        extends Service
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        MyAppAuthenticator authenticator = new MyAppAuthenticator(this);
        return authenticator.getIBinder();
    }
}
```

a default MyAppAuthenticator is required:

```
public class MyAppAuthenticator
        extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator
{
    public MyAppAuthenticator(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    ... etc
```

The manifest also points to authenticator.xml:

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   android:accountType="@string/account_type"
                   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                   android:label="@string/account_name"
                   android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

Finally - just to make the picture complete - there's the string constants:

```
<string name="account_type">my.app.applicationid.account</string>
<string name="account_name">@string/app_title</string>
<string name="account_password">password</string>
```